# Send an email to specific email id when submitting a form was successful

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I'am working with visul studio 2015.
At the client side of my project I have a form that I want to post Its data and save its data to database.
My main problem is when the form posted successfully send an email to a specific email Id.
I have seen a lot of samples with php.But I don't want to use php.
I just want to do it with c# and jQuery.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have the client tell your webserver that the submit was successful and have the webserver send the email

Comment: Is it possible to do it with just javascript or jquery

Comment: where do you want to send the email from on your client? You need some mailserver to handle the mail, i doubt you want/can implement one in javascript. It sounds like you want to use the user's mail, which is quite definately impossible due to security concerns (except for explicitly asking the user, e.g. `mailto:` without guarantee that any mail will actually be sent)

Comment: No I just want to get form data and email to admin that some form data are received recently.I just want to do it automatically by javascript or jquery

Comment: So you need to tell some mailserver, be that your own webserver or some webmail-server that has an API for it or something. But you need to decide where to send the email from.